# How to populate a 2 dimensional array with values from an sql db for the first array and TRUE for the each value of the second array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to populate a 2 dimensional array with values from an sql db for the first array and TRUE for the each value of the second array. When I 'dump' the array, I only get one value (the last value from the images table)
array(2) { ["imgName"]=> string(22) "GlogovacSchutzberg.jpg" ["FLAG"]=> bool(true) }

Please, what am I doing wrong?

```
 $inventoryImageNameArray=array(array(), array());
 foreach ($inventoryImgIdArray as $id){
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *  FROM images");
 $stmt->execute();
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {                 
    if($id == $row['image_id']) {
         $inventoryImageNameArray=array('imgName'=>$row['imageName'],'FLAG'=>TRUE);
                  // echo $row['imageName']. " <BR>";
     }
}
var_dump($inventoryImageNameArray);
```

Comment: You're not *adding* to $inventoryImageNameArray, you're *setting* it(`$inventoryImageNameArray=array(...)`), for every row you fetch. So it'll contain the data from the last time you set it, which was for the last row..)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want the two arrays to contain. Should the first one be a list of image names?

Comment: `$inventoryImageNameArray[]=array('imgName'=>$row['imageName'],'FLAG'=>TRUE);`

Comment: @Nick That would put the flag and imgName in the same array though.. Is that the waya the format should be?

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo it seems to be the most logical interpretation of the question. If I'm wrong I'll happily reopen

Comment: If `$inventoryImageNameArray=array(array(), array());` means anything then I'm not sure. But I'm not sure it does..

Comment: @witgrefe Why do you check `if($id == $row['image_id'])`?

Comment: That is the structure it will end up with `array(array(), array(), array(), ...)` if the code I suggested is used

Comment: You might want to look into an `IN` expression to enable you to fetch all your desired data in one query e.g. something like `SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id IN (` . implode(',', $inventoryImgIdArray) . ')'` (but preferably look up how to prepare such a statement, there are plenty of examples on SO)

Comment: The problem was fixed by adding 2square braces in  as follows $inventoryImageNameArray[]=array("imgName"=>$row['imageName'],"flagStatus"=>$status);

Comment: Torbjorn Stabo asked @witgrefe Why do you check if($id == $row['image_id'])? The reason is I am comparing image_id in 2 tables so that I can get the image name associated with that id,